# Jump to position on page from tweet link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page where I have programmed a sequential access of the bible, with each verse containing a tweet button.

When I tweet a verse, the link redirects to the verses page, but starts at the top.

What I want is that when the tweet link is clicked, it goes to the verses page, and then jumps to the verse position on that page.

Is this possible? Can you help me if so?

This is my current code:

```
<html>
<title>The Bible (Sequential)</title>
<font face="arial">
<?php
define ('HOSTNAME', 'host');
define ('USERNAME', 'user');
define ('PASSWORD', 'pass');
define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'db');

$db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to 
MySQL.');

mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

$query = "SELECT id,book,cap,verse,line FROM bible_kjv ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<p>", ($data_fetch['book']), " ", ($data_fetch['cap']), " ",    
($data_fetch['verse'])," </p>";
echo "<p>", ($data_fetch['line']), "</p>";

echo "<a href='twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='bible-query- 
seq-1.php?id=$data_fetch[id]' 
data-text='The Bible (Sequential): http://mysite/bible-query-seq/bible-query-seq-1.php? 
id=$data_fetch[id]'>Tweet</a>";

echo "<hr>";

}

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();
?>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)  
[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)) 
{js=d.createElement

(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore
(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

<center><a href="bible-query-seq-2.php">Page 2</a></center>
</font>
</html>
```

Comment: You should mark the sections of your page, on each verse include a `<a name="verseNUM">` . when generating the links add #verseNUM to the url , Check out http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Orestes and Pavel, this is what I did; I changed the following:

```
echo "<p>", ($data_fetch['book']), " ", ($data_fetch['cap']), " ",    
($data_fetch['verse'])," </p>";
echo "<p>", ($data_fetch['line']), "</p>";

echo "<a href='twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='bible-query- 
seq-1.php?id=$data_fetch[id]' 
data-text='The Bible (Sequential): http://mysite/bible-query-seq/bible-query-seq-1.php? 
id=$data_fetch[id]'>Tweet</a>";
```

To:

```
echo "<p>", "<a name='$data_fetch[id]'>", ($data_fetch['book']), " ",    
($data_fetch['cap']), " ", ($data_fetch['verse'])," </p>";
echo "<p>", ($data_fetch['line']), "</p>";

echo "<a href='twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='bible-query-  
seq-1.php?id=$data_fetch[id]' 
data-text='The Bible (Sequential): http://mysite/bible-query-
seq/bible-query-seq-1.php?id=$data_fetch[id]#$data_fetch[id]'>Tweet</a>";
```

And it now works!

Answer (score 0):

Totally. You need the id of the HTML element that you would like to scroll to. Say you have a div with id 'verseToScrollTo'. Appending `#verseToScrollTo` at the end of your URL will make the page automatically scroll to that position when the page loads.